# I Can't get it to print the list out

Tags: python, list

```
def main():
    Details = {"Name": [], "Speed": [], "Time": [], "Distance":[] , "Point": []} #This is the list of data
    print ("How many runners are there")
    amount_of_runners = input(" ") #This is to enter the amount of runners
    try: #try this
        amount_of_runners = int(amount_of_runners) #This is an input
    except: #dose that
        print ("Only use a number") #This is so the program catches and wrong format inputs
        main() #SS
    x = 0 #This is so we can input the runners
    while x != amount_of_runners:
        name = input ("Person name ")
        try: #This makes it a string
            name = str(name)
        except: #dose that
            print ("Use letters")
            main()
        speed = int (input("Persons speed ")) #This is the speed
        try:
           speed = int(speed)
        except:
            print ("Use numbers")
            main()
        time = int (input ("How long they ran for ")) #Asks for input
        try:
            time = int(time)

        except:
            print ("Use numbers")
            main() #Returns to menu
        Details["Name"].append(name)
        Details["Speed"].append(int (speed))
        Details["Time"].append(int (time))
        Details["Distance"].append(speed*time)
        Details["Point"].append(x) #This adds to a specific part of a list

        x+=1 # To keep loop
    y = 0
    while y != amount_of_runners: #This area is what will not work the rest dose work
        for i in Details["Point"]:
            if y in i:
                print ("Name is ",[i[0]]," Speed is " ,[i[1]], " Time is " ,    [i[2]], " Distance is ",[i[3]])
        y+=1  




    #Please help
```

I need it to print the list of in an order
I would like it so i = a number
So runner 1 is i
It prints the name speed time and distance of runner 1 
then moves on to the next runner till it is done
        main()

Comment: There are some issues with this code that could be improved on in terms of style, logic etc. Regardless if you get help here, I highly recommend you submit this code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where you will get lots of tips to improve your coding.

Comment: @TomDalton It is true that there are some such issues that can be improved. However, it is important to make it clear that Code Review requires the code to be **working as intended** before being posted there.

Comment: Instead of having details as a `dict` of `lists`, this would probably make more sens,e and be easier to work with if it was a `list` of `dicts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in Details["Point"]:
                if y in i:
                    print ("Name is ",[i[0]]," Speed is " ,[i[1]], " Time is " ,    [i[2]], " Distance is ",[i[3]])
            y+=1
```

The problem is here.  `Details["Point"]:` you are only getting the point (integer) values.  But you are trying to print the list using `i` . This is the problem here

Also i do not know why do you need this `if y in i:` since `i` is integer you would get the error.

```
 while y != amount_of_runners: #This area is what will not work the rest dose work
            for i in Details["Point"]:
                    print ("Name is ", Details["Name"][i]," Speed is " , Details["Speed"][i], " Time is " ,   Details["Time"][i], " Distance is ",Details["Distance"][i])
            y+=1
```

This code will print the below result

o/p

```
How many runners are there
 2
Person name AA
Persons speed 23
How long they ran for 23
Person name BB
Persons speed 23
How long they ran for 34
Name is  AA  Speed is  23  Time is  23  Distance is  529
Name is  BB  Speed is  23  Time is  34  Distance is  782
Name is  AA  Speed is  23  Time is  23  Distance is  529
Name is  BB  Speed is  23  Time is  34  Distance is  782
```

**Why do you need While and for ?**   What o/p you want to print ?

Comment: while y != amount_of_runners: #This area is what will not work the rest dose work
        print ("Name is ", Details["Name"][y]," Speed is " , Details["Speed"][y], " Time is " ,   Details["Time"][y], " Distance is ",Details["Distance"][y])
        y+=1

Comment: You are the best you showed me where i went wrong and now i feel like a idiot lol thanks  mate

Comment: @user3813197 consider upvoding the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

These lines will not work:

```
           for i in Details["Point"]:
                if y in i:
                    print ("Name is ",[i[0]]," Speed is " ,[i[1]], " Time is " ,    [i[2]], " Distance is ",[i[3]])
```

`Details["Point"]` is a list of integers, and the `for` loop loops over each element in the list, so each `i` is an integer.  You can't index an integer, nor can you use `in` on an integer (since `in` checks if something is a member of a sequence, and integers are not sequences).

You probably just want to do `i=Details["Point"]` or something like that:

```
           i = Details["Point"]:
           if y in i:
               print ("Name is ",[i[0]]," Speed is " ,[i[1]], " Time is " ,    [i[2]], " Distance is ",[i[3]])
```

Comment: It comes up with   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "N:\Year's\Year 10\Python\Project\Race.py", line 42, in main
    print ("Name is ",[i[0]]," Speed is " ,[i[1]], " Time is " ,    [i[2]], " Distance is ",[i[3]])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the code you are actually running?  That error message shouldn't  be correct.  You should be getting a `TypeError`.